# Django 1.10 AdminDateWidget() Use in ModelForm

Tags: python, django

The Django docs aren't clear on using ModelForm.  First, how do I set up my urls.py?

I simply do this:

```
from . import views as music_views
url(r'album/add/$', music_views.AlbumCreate(), name='album-add'),
```

In my views I'm trying to use the AdminDateWidget:

```
from . import models as music_models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
class AlbumCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        releasedate = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
        model = music_models.Album
        fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', releasedate, 'notes', 'album_logo', 'rating']
```

My template is:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My struggle here is that I am getting this error when rendering the page:

```
Exception Value:    
sequence item 0: expected str instance, DateField found
```

But according to the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/ docs, DateField is one of the allowable datatypes.  So I am obviously doing it wrong somehow, but don't know how to do it right.  Can someone help me out on this?  I tend to prefer ground up examples to study from, if possible.

Answer (score 8):

At a glance, it seems there are many problems (no form tags in template, fields can only accept strings, etc.) ***But most importantly for those wanting to use AdminDateWidget***: there are a number of extra scripts you need to load which are NOT included in the usual {{ form.media }}.

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from album.views import album_add


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'album/add/$', album_add, name='album-add'),
]
```

**album/models.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    releasedate = models.DateField()


class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    releasedate = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['artist', 'releasedate']
```

**album/views.py**

```
from .models import AlbumForm
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse


def album_add(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = AlbumForm()
        return render(request, 'album/create_album.html', {'form': form})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = AlbumForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Saved.")
        return render(request, 'album/create_album.html', {'form': form})
```

**album/templates/album/create_album.html**

```
{% load static  %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>

{{ form.media }}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}" />

<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Great answer sir !

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

**admin_forms.py**

First add widgets of type `AdminDateWidget` to your date fields. You will need to assign a custom name as css class attribute (`autocomplete=off` is optional, disables autofill)

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('date_start', 'date_end',)
        widgets = {
            'date_start': AdminDateWidget(
                 attrs={'class': 'picker',  'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            'date_end': AdminDateWidget(
                 attrs={'class': 'picker',  'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }
```

**template.html**

Secondly, load necessary resources (datepicker.css)and customise the action of your date fields with class `'picker'` or any name you assigned to your css class. Check the code in the script tag. **IMPORTANT:** For some reason the script tags need to be after the styles to work.

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" />
    <style>
       ... Other CSS ... 
    </style>

   <script>
        grp.jQuery(function () {
            grp.jQuery(".picker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-m-d'});
        });
    </script>

    <form action="{{ action_url }}" method="post" id="my_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <section>
            <fieldset class="module grp-module">
                {% for field in form %}
                    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
        </section>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access to /admin/jsi18n/ requires superuser authentication in Django v.2.0.7. The following line will not work for non-superusers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
```

The workaround is to copy script from this URL to jsi18n.js (being authenticated as a superuser).  Please, note that under each LOCAL_LANGUAGE jsi18n.js has different version, so if you have more then one target LOCAL_LANGUAGE you will need to save different versions of jsi18n.js.